# How to make Candlesticks wider?

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance

I am relatively new to coding, so I apologize beforehand for this simple question:

I want to plot 2week candlesticks.
After I resampled my dataset in 2 week chunks I plotted the results. Unfortunately, matplotlib plots the chart with the complete date range, meaning that there are 14 day gaps between each candle. I already have tried to use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=2))` but this just formats the labels of the x-axis, not the used values.

The Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

candlestick_ohlc(ax, zip(mdates.date2num(quotes.index.to_pydatetime()),
                         quotes['open'], quotes['high'],
                         quotes['low'], quotes['close']),
                 width=0.6)

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

Heres the result:

[image: image of candlesticks with gaps]

So how can I create a continuous graph where the candlesticks are closer to each other ?

[EDIT]
Wow, the simple solution is to put the width higher... I am really sorry for this. It was my first post here :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with minor locator, which makes smaller marks on x axis every day. You can use `ax.xaxis.minorticks_off()` to disable them.

[EDIT]

Hmm, now that I reread the question I think that you want candlesticks to be wider. There is `width` parameter to do just so.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Sorry that my post does not describe my problem clearly enough. I dont want the candlesticks to be wider but to be closer to each other like in a 'normal' candlesticks chart. Right now they are too wide apart from each other.

Comment: Well, they are wide apart because you don't have many datapoints, the plot window is wide and candlesticks themselves are narrow. If you make candlesticks wider they will be closer together, aren't they? Or I don't understand something... If you provide code example I can mess around with it...

Comment: Thank you, you are totally right. The width parameter was it. Sorry that I didnt got your point at first. Have a nice day